# Running fsck on Raid drive

Tags: ssh, raid, fsck, nas

I recently bought an old ix4-300d NAS by Lenovo (obsolete model). It started after some time showing file system error.

I tried to run fsck after connecting to the unit with putty through SSH, which on a dry run does identify a correctible problem. However, despite unmounting the drives and shares, fsck terminates with error saying drive still in use. fuser does not show anything that is using the drive. I also disabled the protocols through the web interface. The reason I cannot use the file system scanner from the web interface is because it does not work. I also cannot touch forcefsck on root FS as the root FS is read-only and the touched file just disappears on reboot.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Many thanks.

[image: Error showing Raid still in use]

[image: my /etc/fstab]

[image: Error on the unit]

[image: All protocols disabled in the web interface]

[image: tail /var/log/messages]

```
root@AdanetCloud:/# vgs
  VG          #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  7d2470b7_vg   1   1   0 wz--n- 14.48t    0
  md0_vg        1   2   0 wz--n- 19.98g    0

root@AdanetCloud:/# lvs
  LV        VG          Attr     LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  lv9953e62 7d2470b7_vg -wi-ao-- 14.48t                                         
  BFDlv     md0_vg      -wi-ao--  4.00g                                         
  vol1      md0_vg      -wi-ao-- 15.98g                                         


root@AdanetCloud:/# df -h Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on /dev/mapper/7d2470b7_vg-lv9953e62 15T 2.6T 12T 18% /mnt/pools/A/A0 ... (truncated)

fsck -yf /dev/mapper/7d2470b7_vg-lv9953e62

root@AdanetCloud:/# fuser -uvm /mnt/pools/A/A0
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/mnt/pools/A/A0:     root     kernel mount (root)/mnt/pools/A/A0
                     root       3512 F.... (root)mt-daapd

[fuser -uvm /mnt/pools/A/A0 after unmounting /mnt/pools/A/A0]

root@AdanetCloud:/# fuser -uvm /mnt/pools/A/A0
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/mnt/pools/A/A0:     root     kernel mount (root)/
                     root          1 .rce. (root)init
                     root          2 .rc.. (root)kthreadd
                     root          3 .rc.. (root)ksoftirqd/0
                     root          6 .rc.. (root)migration/0
                     root          7 .rc.. (root)migration/1
                     root          9 .rc.. (root)ksoftirqd/1
                     root         10 .rc.. (root)khelper
                     root         11 .rc.. (root)netns
                     root        183 .rc.. (root)sync_supers
                     root        185 .rc.. (root)bdi-default
                     root        187 .rc.. (root)kblockd
                     root        193 .rc.. (root)ata_sff
                     root        204 .rc.. (root)khubd
                     root        210 .rc.. (root)md
                     root        228 .rc.. (root)rpciod
                     root        251 .rc.. (root)khungtaskd
                     root        256 .rc.. (root)kswapd0
                     root        257 .rc.. (root)fsnotify_mark
                     root        258 .rc.. (root)unionfs_siod
                     root        259 .rc.. (root)nfsiod
                     root        260 .rc.. (root)xfs_mru_cache
                     root        261 .rc.. (root)xfslogd
                     root        262 .rc.. (root)xfsdatad
                     root        263 .rc.. (root)xfsconvertd
                     root        264 .rc.. (root)crypto
                     root        345 .rc.. (root)iscsi_eh
                     root        348 Frc.m (root)httpd
                     root        361 .rc.. (root)scsi_eh_0
                     root        364 .rc.. (root)scsi_eh_1
                     root        367 .rc.. (root)scsi_eh_2
                     root        370 .rc.. (root)scsi_eh_3
                     root        384 .rc.. (root)scsi_eh_4
                     root        387 .rc.. (root)scsi_eh_5
                     root        393 .rc.. (root)target_completi
                     root        394 .rc.. (root)LIO_rd_mcp
                     root        403 .rc.. (root)mtdblock0
                     root        408 .rc.. (root)mtdblock1
                     root        413 .rc.. (root)mtdblock2
                     root        418 .rc.. (root)mtdblock3
                     root        423 .rc.. (root)mtdblock4
                     root        428 .rc.. (root)mtdblock5
                     root        433 .rc.. (root)mtdblock6
                     root        538 .rc.. (root)scsi_eh_6
                     root        539 .rc.. (root)usb-storage
                     root        558 .rc.. (root)kworker/u:1
                     root        633 .rc.. (root)ubi_bgt0d
                     root        694 .rc.. (root)kworker/0:0
                     root        713 .rc.. (root)ubifs_bgt0_0
                     root        718 .rc.. (root)md0_raid1
                     root        726 .rc.. (root)kdmflush
                     root        735 .rc.. (root)kjournald
                     root        750 .rc.. (root)loop0
                     root        754 .rc.. (root)loop1
                     root        776 .rc.. (root)loop2
                     root        839 .rc.. (root)krfcommd
                     root        920 .rc.. (root)flush-7:1
                     root       1049 Frc.m (root)udevd
                     root       2172 Frc.m (root)logsave
                     root       2484 Frc.m (root)rsyslogd
                     root       2554 .rc.. (root)bond0
                     root       2705 .rc.. (root)kworker/0:1
                     root       2795 Frc.m (root)dhclient
                     nobody     2934 Frc.m (nobody)mdnsd
                     root       2936 .rc.m (root)hostnamed
                     root       2949 Fr..m (root)appmd
                     root       2960 Frc.m (root)getty
                     root       2973 Fr..m (root)dbus-daemon
                     root       2975 Fr..m (root)eventd
                     nobody     3007 Frc.m (nobody)mdnsd
                     root       3009 .rc.m (root)hostnamed
                     root       3010 Fr..m (root)pkgd
                     root       3026 Fr..m (root)upnpdiscovery
                     nobody     3029 Fr..m (nobody)mdnsd
                     root       3031 Frc.m (root)sshd
                     root       3033 Fr..m (root)svcd
                     root       3037 Fr..m (root)acpid
                     root       3043 Fr..m (root)imgd
                     root       3057 Frc.m (root)lld2d
                     root       3058 Fr..m (root)sh
                     root       3060 Fr..m (root)sh
                     root       3077 Frc.m (root)httpd
                     root       3102 Fr..m (root)pcloudd
                     root       3105 Fr..m (root)activefolder
                     root       3243 Fr..m (root)sleep
                     root       3320 Frc.m (root)cron
                     root       3371 Frc.m (root)netplugd
                     root       3463 Frc.m (root)sshd
                     root       3478 .rc.m (root)sh
                     root       3556 .rc.. (root)flush-ubifs_0_0
                     root       3601 Fr..m (root)sleep
                     root       3678 Fr..m (root)sleep
                     root       3900 Frc.m (root)udevd
                     root       3902 Frc.m (root)udevd
                     root       4042 .rc.. (root)kdmflush
                     root       4087 .rc.. (root)kdmflush
                     root       4099 .rc.. (root)jbd2/dm-1-8
                     root       4100 .rc.. (root)ext4-dio-unwrit
                     root       4105 .rc.. (root)jbd2/dm-2-8
                     root       4106 .rc.. (root)ext4-dio-unwrit
                     root       4110 .rc.. (root)flush-253:1
                     root       4149 .rc.. (root)ufsd_sdd1
                     root       4316 Fr..m (root)displayd
                     root       4340 Fr..m (root)quiktransfer
                     root       4343 Fr..m (root)logrotation
                     root       4384 Fr..m (root)datamover
                     root       4459 Fr..m (root)connectd
                     root       4483 Fr..m (root)amazon
                     root       4548 Fr..m (root)Transmission
                     root       4550 Fr..m (root)transmission-da
                     root       4607 Fr..m (root)smbd
                     root       4611 Fr..m (root)winbindd
                     root       4616 Fr..m (root)mysqlserver
                     root       4683 Fr..m (root)winbindd
                     root       4839 Fr..m (root)smbd-notifyd
                     root       4840 Fr..m (root)cleanupd
                     root       4850 Fr..m (root)winbindd
                     root       4856 Fr..m (root)winbindd
                     root       4887 Fr..m (root)lpqd
                     root       4952 Fr..m (root)nmbd
                     root       4974 Fr..m (root)mysqld_safe
                     root       5202 Fr..m (root)rsync
                     root       5439 Fr..m (root)twonkystart.sh
                     root       5447 Fr..m (root)su
                     root       5451 Frc.m (root)isnsd
                     nobody     5459 Fr..m (nobody)twonkyserver
                     mysql      5837 Fr..m (mysql)mysqld
                     root       5985 .rc.. (root)scst_release_ac
                     root       5991 .rc.. (root)scst_uid
                     root       5995 .rc.. (root)scstd0
                     root       5998 .rc.. (root)scstd1
                     root       5999 .rc.. (root)scst_initd
                     root       6000 .rc.. (root)scsi_tm
                     root       6001 .rc.. (root)scst_mgmtd
                     root       6044 .rc.. (root)iscsird0_0
                     root       6045 .rc.. (root)iscsird0_1
                     root       6046 .rc.. (root)iscsird0_2
                     root       6049 .rc.. (root)iscsird0_3
                     root       6051 .rc.. (root)iscsiwr0_0
                     root       6052 .rc.. (root)iscsiwr0_1
                     root       6053 .rc.. (root)iscsiwr0_2
                     root       6055 .rc.. (root)iscsiwr0_3
                     root       6066 Frc.m (root)iscsi-scstd
                     root       6247 .rc.. (root)kworker/u:0
                     root      15522 Frc.m (root)httpd
                     root      16215 .rc.. (root)kworker/1:1
                     root      23662 Frc.m (root)httpd
                     root      26558 .rc.. (root)flush-253:2
                     root      32367 .rc.. (root)kworker/1:2

[After trying to run fsck on unmounted drive]

root@AdanetCloud:/# fsck /dev/mapper/7d2470b7_vg-lv9953e62
fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
/dev/mapper/7d2470b7_vg-lv9953e62 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139722/discussion-on-question-by-alexa-running-fsck-on-raid-drive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue.

1. Enabled SSH (support mode) and logged into unit [UN: root; PW: soho+password] using a SSH client (e.g. Putty on windows or JuiceSSH on Android).
2. Shutdown all "Protocols" via the web GUI that would access the drive, NFS, Windows Share, Media server [I did not disable media server before and hence the raid drive was in use].
3. Unmounted all of the NFS shared folders and the pool mounts [use df -h to see what folders are mounted to your drive (/dev/mapper/7d2470b7_vg-lv9953e62 for me) and use umount.
4. Once everything is unmounted, run fsck on the RAID drive, run fsck -yfVC /dev/mapper/7d2470b7_vg-lv9953e62.
5. Then let it run and correct any errors found. You can have 2 separate runs of this to ensure all errors are fixed.
6. If significant fragmentation (>1%), run e4defrag /dev/mapper/7d2470b7_vg-lv9953e62 after reboot once the file system is mounted (as opposed to fsck, which would not run on mounted file system)
7. Run iostat -x and examine %b for each drive. The one that is under-performing (or about to fail) will have high wait times compared the the rest and usually the %b will be near 100%. This drive would need to be replaced.
8. Reboot (run reboot or shutdown now)

Thanks everyone.